# Why is my ngRoute not working

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

My ngroute works for my homepage however when i click the link to go to my education page it runs .otherwise rather then running .which('/education ... and showing the proper templateUrl

**home.html**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('Danielle', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider

.when('/',{
controller:'HomeController',
templateUrl:'views/homepage.html'
})      

.when('/education',{
  templateUrl:'views/education.html'
})

.otherwise({ 
  redirectTo: '/' 
}); 
});
```

**homepage.html**

```
<style>
body{
   background: url(/img/3kzlcl3rj8a-ricardo-gomez-angel.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
 }
</style>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Danielle Zurek</h1>
<a href="#/education.html">
<div class="education">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Education</h2>
    </div>
</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**education.html**

```
<style>
body{
   background: url(/img/grads.jpg) no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Education</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Never mind i solve this almost immediately after i posted it. The error lied in homepage.html `<a href="#/education.html">` should have been `<a href="#/education">`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It may be helpful to others if you post an answer to your question and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the name of view, into ng-view
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Answer (score 0):

Although you already found the issue, and have resolve this as per your comment. But there is something you should really consider moving ahead. When you are working with the MVC frameworks, then you should always consider changing application routes using the router. Using, `href="#/education"` or something like `$window.location.href` actually refreshes your page, that simply means that it would re-initiate your application.

You should always keep `href="javascript:void(0)"`, which would stop the page refresh. To change routes you should use `$location.path()` in your controller.

Comment: when adding `$location.path(...)` how do i make it so that the link in the view actually brings me to that path?

Comment: also would doing this, once i figure this out, stop my ng-route animations from being choppy. cause now that i know this i figure that the choppyness of the animation transitions is due to it loading the browsers again.